# No pagination in Document Set/Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, list-view, document-set

I have a document set library that does not paginate the files within each document set.

I can see a total of 30 files within each document set but the page controls to see the second page of files are missing, and I don't think I've ever seen them.

I'm deploying the document set as a solution. Below is the XML for the view (that is displayed on the document set home page) in the library's schema:

```
  <View BaseViewID="2" Name="a6ec330a-687b-4757-be16-81d59e31bc65"  DisplayName="All Files" Type="HTML" ReadOnly="FALSE" WebPartZoneID="Main" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" Url="This Project.aspx" TargetType="ContentType" TargetId="0x0120D52000E48C8C06BD0A4884930EC0083E355F97" Hidden="TRUE">
    <RowLimit>30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
      <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" />
      <FieldRef Name="FileSizeDisplay" />
      <FieldRef Name="FileCategory" />
      <FieldRef Name="Created" />
      <FieldRef Name="Author" />
      <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
      <FieldRef Name="Editor" />
      <FieldRef Name="DoNotShare" />
    </ViewFields>
    <Query />
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
  </View>
```

Comment: try with this one  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this **Paged="TRUE"** into RowLimit tag, that would be like as `<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>.`